# How to use pagable object with custom Query in Spring

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate

I am trying to use a custom query with pageble object , but i am not getting the correct output for it.In a word it's not working for me . Every time i am calling the Api it's giving me the incorrect result.I a posting the code what i have done so far

```
@Repository
public class kBookHistoryCustomRepository {


@PersistenceContext
private EntityManager entityManager;


public Page<KookHistoryEntity> searchkMatchedCriteria(KookSearchDto kookSearchDto,
        Pageable pageable) {


    
    List<KookHistoryEntity> kookHistoryDetailsList = new ArrayList<>();
    Page<KookHistoryEntity> page = null;
    int st = Integer.parseInt(kookSearchDto.getStoreNumber());
    LocalDate from= kookSearchDto.getFromdate();
    LocalDate to= kookSearchDto.getTodate();
    int lk_id = 0;


    String query = "SELECT CH.mar,CH.st , CH.so, CH.k_date , CH.ck_date , "
            + "CH.corr_code,CH.line_id,CH.line_description ,"
            
            + " FROM ck.k_history CH WHERE 1 = 1  ";

    if (!StringUtils.isEmpty(store)) {
        query = query + "AND    CH.st = :st ";
    }



    query = query + "AND CH.kbook_date BETWEEN  :to AND :from";

    if (!StringUtils.isEmpty(kBookSearchDto.getLk())) {

        line_id = Integer.parseInt(kBookSearchDto.getLineId());
        query = query + " AND    CH.line_id = :lk_id ";
    }

    Query sqlQuery = entityManager.createNativeQuery(query); //creating the Query here 
    sqlQuery.setParameter("st", st);
    sqlQuery.setParameter("from", from);
    sqlQuery.setParameter("to",to);
    if(lk_id>0)
    sqlQuery.setParameter("lk_id",lk_id);
    List<Object[]> objectList = sqlQuery.getResultList();

    objectList.forEach(glObject -> {
        KookHistoryEntity kookHistoryEntity = KookHistoryEntity.builder()
                .market((BigDecimal)glObject[0])
                .stNumber((BigDecimal) glObject[1])
                .so((String)glObject[2])
                .eDate((Date)glObject[3])
                .pDate((Date)glObject[4])
                .cCode((String)glObject[5])
                .....some more field
                .build();

        kookHistoryDetailsList.add(kookHistoryEntity);

    });
    page = new PageImpl<>(kookHistoryDetailsList,pageable,objectList.size()); //setting the page object here 

    return page;
}
```

}

I am not able to do the pagination using this code, can anyone help me .

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass the paging param in query and have the query return paginated data to applications.
Set `setFirstResult` to return data from that offset and use `setMaxResults` to get get data of the page size.
You will also need a count query to set the totalCount in Page object.
Your code will look something like this.

```
    public Page<KookHistoryEntity> searchkMatchedCriteria(KookSearchDto kookSearchDto,
                                                          Pageable pageable) {

        List<KookHistoryEntity> kookHistoryDetailsList = new ArrayList<>();
        Page<KookHistoryEntity> page = null;
        int st = Integer.parseInt(kookSearchDto.getStoreNumber());
        LocalDate from= kookSearchDto.getFromdate();
        LocalDate to= kookSearchDto.getTodate();
        int lk_id = 0;


        String whereClaus = " FROM ck.k_history CH WHERE 1 = 1  ";

        if (!StringUtils.isEmpty(store)) {
            whereClaus = whereClaus + "AND    CH.st = :st ";
        }

        whereClaus = whereClaus + "AND CH.kbook_date BETWEEN  :to AND :from";

        if (!StringUtils.isEmpty(kBookSearchDto.getLk())) {

            line_id = Integer.parseInt(kBookSearchDto.getLineId());
            whereClaus = whereClaus + " AND    CH.line_id = :lk_id ";
        }

        String query = "SELECT CH.mar,CH.st , CH.so, CH.k_date , CH.ck_date , "
                + "CH.corr_code,CH.line_id,CH.line_description ,"
                + whereClaus;

        String countQueryString = "SELECT count(*) "
                + whereClaus;

        Query sqlQuery = entityManager.createNativeQuery(query); //creating the Query here
        sqlQuery.setParameter("st", st);
        sqlQuery.setParameter("from", from);
        sqlQuery.setParameter("to",to);
        sqlQuery.setFirstResult(pageable.getPageNumber()*pageable.getPageSize());
        sqlQuery.setMaxResults(pageable.getPageSize());
        if(lk_id>0)
            sqlQuery.setParameter("lk_id",lk_id);
        List<Object[]> objectList = sqlQuery.getResultList();

        Query countQuery = entityManager.createNativeQuery(countQueryString);
        sqlQuery.setParameter("st", st);
        sqlQuery.setParameter("from", from);
        sqlQuery.setParameter("to",to);
        if(lk_id>0)
            sqlQuery.setParameter("lk_id",lk_id);
        Long count = (Long) countQuery.getSingleResult();

        objectList.forEach(glObject -> {
            KookHistoryEntity kookHistoryEntity = KookHistoryEntity.builder()
                    .market((BigDecimal)glObject[0])
                    .stNumber((BigDecimal) glObject[1])
                    .so((String)glObject[2])
                    .eDate((Date)glObject[3])
                    .pDate((Date)glObject[4])
                    .cCode((String)glObject[5])
                .....some more field
                    .build();

            kookHistoryDetailsList.add(kookHistoryEntity);

        });

        page = new PageImpl<>(kookHistoryDetailsList,pageable,count); //setting the page object here

        return page;
    }
```

Comment: can you please edit my code, not able to understand how to manage

Comment: I have tried my best to edit your code. Hope this helps.